# ROBOT FRAMEWORK: Does test teardown execute if test case is skipped using robot:skip tag?

Tags: robotframework

I have 4 test cases in test suite. Because of code changes, one of test case is failing. So I am skipping that test case using robot:skip tag. Suite has "Test Teardown" in Setting section. "Test Teardown" functionality is to updates status of test case to Slack channel.

When I execute test suite, test case status for SKIPed test is not updated to Slack channel i.e.  "Test Teardown" is not working for SKIPed test case. Test case status for PASS and FAIL test case is updated properly.

So I want to know - Does Test Teardown execute even if test case is skipped ?

Example - My SKIPed test case

```
*** Settings ***
Library             OperatingSystem
Resource          ${CURDIR}${/}..//..//Resources//global.resource
Library      Selenium2Library
Test Teardown    Update Status To Slack Channel At End Of Run


Verify All 24 Athletes Appear On Web Reporting Tab Within 15 min Of Processing
    [Tags]  robot:skip
    Log     Skipping this test. Reason - xyz
    . . . . . .
```

Logic used to updated Slack channel - Working for PASS and FAIL test cases but not for SKIPed test case.

```
Update Status To Slack Channel At End Of Run 
    [Tags]    post
    Log      ${body}
   
  IF  ${EnableSlackMessages}

    FOR    ${key}    IN    @{body}
        Log    ${key}=${body}[${key}]
        Log    ${body}[${key}]
        Log    ${key}
        Log     ${stsTrue}
        Log     ${stsFalse}
        
        ${testStatus}=  Convert To String  ${body}[${key}] 
        Log     ${testStatus}
        IF    ('${testStatus}' == 'PASS')
            # Green Tick Ascii \u2705 - for Pass TCs
            # Red round Ascii \uE219   
            # Red cros Ascii \u274C -for failed TCs
             ${item}    Set Variable    \u2705 
        ELSE IF  ('${testStatus}' == 'FAIL')
                # Red cross Ascii
                 ${item}    Set Variable    \u274C
        ELSE 
**                # In case of SKIPed test . Fast forward sign unicode 
                ${item}    Set Variable    \u23E9**
        END
        Log         ${item}
            ${body1}=    Create Dictionary    text= ${key} ${body}[${key}] ${item}    channel=ABCD1234
            Log    ${body1}
        
            ${resp}=    POST    ${HTTP_LOCAL_SERVER}   json=${body1}
            Status Should Be    OK    ${resp}
    END
  END
```

When I execute test suite [ Total 4 test cases - 3 Pass  / 1 Skip], test case status for SKIPed test is not updated in slack channel. Test case status for PASS and FAIL test case is updated properly. It is possible that my logic to update Slack channel for SKIP test case is flawed.

So I want to know - Does Test Teardown execute even if test case is skipped ?